# unable to point swarm master on EC2 to consul registry on another EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-machine, consul

I am receiving the following error when trying to point a swarm master on one EC2 instance to a registry using Consul on another EC2 instance:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(swarm-master) Launching instance...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with ubuntu(systemd)...
Installing Docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: ssh command error:
command : sudo systemctl -f start docker
err     : exit status 1
output  : Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I've noted tips to point directly to a docker engine location, upgraded to the latest docker-machine version, and opened port 8500 on the registry EC2's security group, but this did not resolve my issue.

Here is how I'm running:

create registry:

```
docker-machine create \
        --driver amazonec2 \
        --amazonec2-vpc-id vpc-12345678 \
        --amazonec2-region us-east-1 \
        --amazonec2-zone b \
        --amazonec2-instance-type t2.micro \
        --amazonec2-subnet-id subnet-12345678 \
        --amazonec2-security-group swarm_sg \
        --amazonec2-keypair-name swarm \
        --amazonec2-ssh-keypath ~/.docker/machine/certs/swarm \
        swarm-registry
```

assume registry machine

```
eval $(docker-machine env swarm-registry)
```

run consul

```
docker run -d \
        -p "8500:8500" \
        -h "consul" \
        progrium/consul -server -bootstrap
```

create swarm master:

```
docker-machine create \
        --driver amazonec2 \
        --amazonec2-vpc-id vpc-12345678 \
        --amazonec2-region us-east-1 \
        --amazonec2-zone b \
        --amazonec2-instance-type t2.micro \
        --amazonec2-subnet-id subnet-12345678 \
        --amazonec2-security-group swarm_sg \
        --amazonec2-keypair-name swarm \
        --amazonec2-ssh-keypath ~/.docker/machine/certs/swarm \
        --engine-install-url="https://web.archive.org/web/20170623081500/https://get.docker.com" \
        --swarm \
        --swarm-master \
        --swarm-discovery="consul://172.31.56.214:8500" \
        --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://172.31.56.214:8500" \
        --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth1:2376" \
        swarm-master
```

where 172.31.56.214 is the private IP address of the swarm-registry machine's host EC2.  furthermore, when running w/o trying to point to Consul i don't have a problem.  that is, creating the master without the following lines is possible:

```
        --swarm-discovery="consul://172.31.56.214:8500" \
        --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://172.31.56.214:8500" \
        --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth1:2376" \
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was my network interface name was not eth1.  It is eth0.  As an aside, I'd be interested in understanding how AWS interfaces are named.  They appear to vary across our EC2 instance types (e.g. eth0, eth1, ens3).